# Matching part of a DFG in Prolog

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, grammar, context-free-grammar

I have defined a DFG grammar in Prolog which is something like this:

```
start --> subject, verb, object.
subject --> ([i]; [you]).
verb --> ([like]; [need]).
object --> article, noun.
article --> ([my];[your]).
noun --> ([car] ; [bike]).
```

Now, I would like to have a predicate that returned me the object part of a phrase accepted by this DFG.

For example, `objectPart([i, like, my, car], X)` should return `X = [my, car]`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done:

```
start(O) --> subject, verb, my_object(O).
subject --> ([i]; [you]).
verb --> ([like]; [need]).
my_object(L) --> article(A), noun(N), {L = [A,N]}.
article(A) --> ([my],{A=my};[your],{A=your}).
noun(N) --> ([car],{N=car} ; [bike],{N=bike}).

objectPart(Lst, R) :-
    phrase(start(R), Lst).
```

Result :

```
?- objectPart([i, like, your, car], Z).
Z = [your, car] .
```

**EDIT** I change **object** in **my_object** because SWI-Prolog use object for XPCE.